# how to get the address of an specific location in android?

Tags: android, gps, location

I use [Google Location API](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) to get the location of the user every 5 seconds and it works fine. then I must know the address of that location. I know I can use `Geocoder.getFromLocation` but as [documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) say, it is not always available, and it needs an internet network to work. is there another reliable way to get the address offline?

Answer (score 1):

That is practically impossible, because you need to have a lot of information about which address is tied to (approximately) which lat/long value.

However, one solution is to include such a database in your application. It seems like [MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) open sourced theirs quite some time ago. However, the best you can get there is cities, which is probably not what you are looking for.

So unless you are able to find a database with such information, this is not possible without internet connection.

Comment: as you know, there are lots of offline maps which allow you to see your location on them. offline maps have street name, city name and ... with themselves, too. so is it possible to retrieve the street name of a location from an offline map?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another reliable way to get the address offline?

So for sure with Geocoder you are not able to get it work without backend service in this case network.

If you want to have offline access to maps, they have to be stored in your device to be able reading them. So you have only one choice and download map data, try to process them (optimize size for mobile devices) and you have to create some structure where you will store data for fast-searching (most likely quad tree or R-tree)<sup>**1**</sup>. It's not trivial at all. Or (assume if exists) use some offline maps but also data must be stored in your device.

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>I have been working on some personal project focused for offline address searching. I'm using OpenStreetMaps as data source. But i can tell you it's not that easy. Since raw data are stored in a huge XML files (1-600 GB) i had to create convesion tool for desktop that processes data and saves them in quad tree that is serialised into database (tree is a huge and cannot be added to memory so i need to cache it and use semi-persistence). In other words tool prepares data for an usage in device. Final files have approximate 100 MB - 1 GB (depends on source size). I could tell you more but this is not right place.</sub>

I have done some speed performance test and only for "illustration" i compared performance with official Geocoder API:

[image]

But tool is not done but works as you can see above. I think performance is not bad but i think can be optimized (optimized statements and tree algorithms).